Number of non-isomorphic sub-trees of a tree with n vertices
Does any of you know any upper bound for it better than $O(2^n)$?
I try to create a dynamic programming algorithm which goes through all subtrees of a given tree. I wonder whether it is possible to go through all of there subtrees in polynomial or maybe quasipolynomial time.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The paper by Czabarka, Székely, and Wagner, On the number of nonisomorphic subtrees of a tree, available at https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/am-pdf/10.1002/jgt.22144 says, "We show that a tree of order $n$ has at most $O(5^{n/4})$ nonisomorphic subtrees, and that this bound is best possible."

Thank you a lot, this is exactly what i was looking for

Do you know maybe how many can there nonisomorphic subtrees of given size $k$?
